# Matter of course use of future continuous

Tags: tenses, future, continuous-aspect

I am unable to fully grasp the matter of course use future continuous.
The explanation says;

> we use future continuous to talk about something which will happen, if everything happens as we expect

An example sentence is;

> the government will be making an announcement later.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: What is there about it that's confusing?

Answer (score 1):

I think the explanation you cite is a good one.

The government will make an announcement later. (There is no question of this. Short of an earthquake or other national disaster, they ***will*** make the announcement.)

The government will be making an announcement later. (This has a certain tentativeness about it. It says, "All being well, the government will make the announcement.")

The difference is very small in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it's much more clear now.